# as necessary / as was necessary / as it was necessary

Tags: conjunctions, as

> The general public have never dealt with it as seriously **as was necessary.**
>
> The general public have never dealt with it as seriously **as it was necessary.**
>
> The general public have never dealt with it as seriously **as necessary.**

Would you tell me which one is acceptable?

Comment: This question is focused on a single issue and should not be closed as proofreading. That said, it could certainly be improved if OP chose to supply more details around the thought process thus far–this makes it easier for someone else to write an answer that addresses the specific issue in a way that makes the most sense to you and disentangles the exact issue as it exists in your thinking without guessing as to what your thinking on the topic might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, we use as necessary, if necessary, when necessary, etc. that can be used for all tenses. I think it is unnecessary to use "was" and  "it was" in the first two phrases . So the third phrase "The general public has/have never dealt with it as seriously as necessary" seems suitable.

Answer (score 0):

The first two have mixed tenses (assuming you mean this to be in the present tense) so I would not use them.

> The general public **has** never dealt with it as seriously as necessary.

is OK, and *as necessary* does not change the tense. Also it is usually a good idea to omit extra words that are not needed.
But you have to use **has**, because *general public* is a mass noun and therefore treated as singular.